# JQuery add element needs jquery script to be added again just before my js

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla

I am trying a following piece of JQuery code to add element dynamically.

Scenarios:
a) If I include the below script and jquery.min.js in  it doesnt work.
b) If I add the below script in body and jquery.min.js in  still it doesnt work.
c) If I add the below script in body and jquery.min.js just above the below **code then it work. Why is this so?**

Also I need to have jquery.min.js in head for the other functionality of joomla to work. Is it ok to add jquery.min.js in both head and in body.

I am using jQuery v@1.8.1

Please help me to understand the above scenario.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
var count = 0;
$('p#add_field').click(function(){
count += 1;
$('#container').append(
'<strong>Link #' + count + '</strong><br />' + '<input id="field_' + count + '" name="fields[]' + '" type="text" /><br />' );
});
});
</script>
```

Below piece is the code which gets added dynamically.

```
<div id="container">
        <p id="add_field"><a href="#"><span>&raquo; Add your favourite links.....</span></a></p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you get that code from some place involving MooTools?

try wrapping in this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  //do stuff
})
```

link for your reference
http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-domready

So the result could be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {//shorthand way of doing document.ready
        var count = 0;
        $('p#add_field').click(function(){
            count += 1;
            $('#container').append(
                '<strong>Link #' + count + '</strong><br />' + '<input id="field_' + count + '" name="fields[]' + '" type="text" /><br />' );
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I am trying to develop a plugin for my joomla website. It does have both mootool and joomla. the one you have suggested worked for me. thank you

Answer (score 1):

The reason that it works when you add the including `script` tags for jQuery before the actual script is because the script makes use of jQuery to perform what it does. In JavaScript you have access to a script's functionality in the order that they are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

In your document:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var count = 0;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('p#add_field').click(function(){
                count += 1;
                $('#container').append('<strong>Link #' + count + '</strong><br />' + '<input id="field_' + count + '" name="fields[]' + '" type="text" /><br />' );
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
$document =& JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript("jquery-1.8.1.min.js");
$js = " $(document).ready(function() {
    var count = 0;
    $('p#add_field').click(function(){
      count += 1;
      $('#container').append('<strong>Link #' + count + '</strong><br />' + '<input id="field_' + count + '" name="fields[]' + '" type="text" /><br />' );
    });
});";
$document->addScriptDeclaration($js);
```